# Is it possible to let us remove a reject vote on an edit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was checking out questions (not through the review queue), when I came upon [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10967984) that I rejected. However, in the comments for the question, I noticed that the posted the edit took the OP's comment and added it to the question.

I hadn't gone through the comments yet (***so totally my fault that I mistakenly rejected the edit***), and it appeared to me as someone "trying to help" by posting suggested code that should have been an answer.

I'm sure the other fine reviewers (who pay attention) will get the edit to pass, but I still wonder if there should possibly be an "oh crap, I missed why it was done" way to remove a vote to reject. Even if I can't vote to accept the edit, it was still completely wrong of me to vote to reject it.