# Undo suggested edit rejection for an edit on my own post?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I woke up this morning to find that I had a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10971729) on one of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015423/344733). The suggested edit had already been rejected. However, the edit is actually a good one, and in my opinion should have been approved. Is there anyway to undo or flag the rejection? I can of course edit the answer myself, but would like to give credit to the original suggester if possible.

Comment: Didn't I see this asked already here today?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to accept an edit that has already been rejected. If you really want to give credit to the editor you could ask him in a comment on one of his posts, and then accept it, but you should both be online at the same time, otherwise it may get rejected again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I searched for duplicates but didn't find this exact question. I certainly didn't ask before now.

Comment: @user000001, thanks for the suggestion. That's probably too much work for such a simple edit.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I just meant [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315140/is-it-possible-to-let-us-remove-a-reject-vote-on-an-edit) a few questions below.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, makes sense. That's not quite the same thing since I'm not asking about undoing my own bad vote, rather the edit was rejected by other people before I saw it at all.

Comment: No need to give credit for something that should not been done. This is invalid edit for anyone. There is no way edit changing `NSNumber *buildNumber...` to `NSString *buildNumber ...` would be approved unless one spends inappropriately large amount of time on review: this is code change (95% reject) and it changes something that called "number" (with sample value of 42) into type of "string".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That edit should have been a comment on your answer, not an edit to your answer.  Any concerns with the content and quality of the code in an answer should be made to the original poster as a comment, not an edit.  When an edit like this comes up, it looks to the reviewers like another user is trying to introduce content that "deviates from the original intent of the post" (as quoted from the edit rejection reason).

If you feel that the edit is helpful, you can edit your answer to include this change with a link to the suggested edit, and optionally a reference to the user.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I suppose I didn't know exactly what constitutes a good edit in this case. His edit _does_ fix an obvious and simple bug in my code. Are edits then only meant to fix superficial problems, e.g. formatting and typographical errors?

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I feel that edits should be used to fix grammar, tags, and (sometimes) spacing issues.  But ultimately it is up to the reviewers.  When I see a user suggesting an edit that adds a link to a tutorial or additional code (which may or may not be relevant to the question/answer), I generally reject because I don't want to put words in the original answer's mouth.

Comment: On the other hand, if I see a very low quality question with a superficial suggested edit (correcting grammar), I usually chose "causes harm" with the custom reason "Question should be closed."

Comment: In this case, I feel that this edit should have been a comment because it addresses (and corrects) an issue with your post.  The user who suggested the edit could also have added their own (potentially more correct) answer, addressing the issues with your answer.

Comment: Most code-changing edits should be rejected, but this is not a rule carved in stone. It would have been better for the editor to first discuss it in comments. Then, if enough people or the OP confirm, the editor can write in the edit summary, "as discussed in comments".

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I appreciate the clarification, as it will help me with similar situations in the future, including when reviewing suggested edits myself. I've edited my original answer to reflect the suggested change, as well.

Comment: @JAL I've also seen edits move comments to an answer that was the actual answer(or corrected/completed it) and from the answerer themselves. Sometimes the answerer is given a few days to make the edit themselves. At least with that situation it's not putting words into their mouth, but making the answer more complete without risking the comments getting deleted.